# optimize xargs argument enumeration

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

Can this usage of xargs argument enumaration be optimized better?
The aim is to inject single argument in the middle of the actual command.

I do:

```
echo {1..3} | xargs -I{} sh -c 'for i in {};do echo line $i here;done'
```

or

```
echo {1..3} | for i in $(xargs -n1);do echo line $i here; done
```

I get:

```
line 1 here
line 2 here
line 3 here
```

which is what I need but I wondered if loop and temporary variable could be avoided?

Comment: `for i in {1..3}; do echo line $i here; done`?

Comment: Your question is really not clear and really looks like an XY problem. What specific use case do you have in mind? There's very likely a much better design than what you're asking for.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - just looking for a neat way of arguments usage, passed through a pipe anywhere in subsequent command

Comment: That's not really a specific use case. To me, this looks like a broken design from the start. And if you're not experimented in shell scripting, there are lots of caveats you're overlooking (most of them coming from the fact that you're clearly mixing code and data). From here on, one possible scenario is that you'll wrongly learn bad techniques that will bite you in the back sooner than you'll expect.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - thanks for your valuable comment.Would you mind pointing me to a resource where I could learn appropriate separation of code and data in the context of shell scripting?

Comment: @Trebor: I don't really know of any good resources that specifically focus on this point. I can only recommend the best resource on Bash I know of: [The BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [The BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). This material is known to be accurate, made by possibly the most knowledgeable and active persons, and is up to date with modern techniques (unlike too many sources out there that are either plain wrong or plain outdated, showing antipatterns and obsolete methods all over the place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without `xargs`. For most situations `xargs` is overkill.
Depending on what you really want you can choose a solution like

```
# Normally you want to avoid for and use while, but here you want the things splitted.
for i in $(echo {1 2 3} );do 
   echo line $i here;
done

# When you want 1 line turned into three, `tr` can help
echo {1..3} | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/.*/line & here/'

# printf will repeat itself when there are parameters left
printf "line %s here\n" $(echo {1..3})

# Using the printf feature you can avoid the echo
printf "line %s here\n"  {1..3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the input to `xargs` by newlines:

```
echo {1..3}$'\n' | xargs -I% echo line % here
```

For array expansions, you can use `printf`:

```
ar=({1..3})
printf '%s\n' "${ar[@]}" | xargs -I% echo line % here
```

(and if it's just for output, you can use it without `xargs`:

```
printf 'line %s here\n' "${ar[@]}"
```

)

Comment: I did not know about the brace expansion handling prefixes and suffixes.  Good to know.  It might be worth mentioning that this will not work in other scenarios involving other types of expansion (e.g. expanding all elements in an array).

Comment: Note that `echo {1..3}$'\n'` expands to `echo 1$'\n' 2$'\n' 3$'\n'`, so that `echo` sees three arguments. Now `echo` prints its arguments _separated by a space,_ so the `2` and `3` will be prefixed with a space, and you'll also get an empty trailing line (since `echo` also adds a newline at the end). This will cause problems if, later, you want to use (GNU) `xargs` more robustly with `-d\\n`. The `printf` version is obviously superior and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
echo {1..3} | tr " " "\n" | xargs -n1 sh -c ' echo "line $0 here"'
```

The `tr` replaces the spaces with newlines, so `xargs` sees three lines.  I would not be surprised if there were a better (more efficient) solution, but this one is quite simple.

Please note I have modified my previous answer to remove the use of `{}`, which was suggested in the comments to eliminate a potential code injection vulnerability.

Comment: More idiomatically, use `printf '%s\n' {1..3}`.

Comment: Quite right.  I will not update my answer, the other one is already better and more complete, while mine, while not the best, is not wrong either.

Comment: Note that your use of `{}` _within `sh` code_ is a very bad thing: you're _mixing code with data!_ (which is one of the main sources of problems, and a horrible antipattern you should recognize and get rid of). Indeed, it's very easy to forge data that will produce arbitrary code execution, e.g., `printf '%s\n' 'one; rm -rf some_precious_directory #' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo line {} here;'`, you'll get some surprises! you must handle _data_ as _data._ For this: `... | xargs -n1 sh -c ' echo "line $1 here"' sh`. The same mistake is commonly found with `find`'s `-exec sh -c '... {} ...' \;`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I would like to modify my answer to correct this problem, but I cannot get the code you are suggesting for xargs to work either with "printf" or with the "tr"-based solution ($1 expands to nothing), all I get printed is "line  here".  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf actually, it works if I replace $1 by $0.  Is that OK?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' {1..3} | xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo "line $1 here"' sh`. Note the trailing `sh` here, that will be used as the positional parameter `$0`. You could also use: `printf '%s\n' {1..3} | xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo "line $0 here"'` but usually people find it awkward to use `$0`, so it is customary to feed `sh -c` with a dummy `$0`-th parameter, usually `sh` (but it could be anything else).

Comment: Ok, got it.  I prefer "$0".  If I were to use some trailing value, I would probably use something like DUMMY to make it clear that it is just that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a not well known feature of GNU sed. You can add the `e` flag to the `s` command and then sed executes whatever is in the pattern space and replaces the pattern space with the output if that command.

If you are really only interested in the output of the echo commands, you might try this GNU sed example, which eliminates the temporary variable, the loop (and the xargs as well):

```
echo {1..3} | sed -r 's/([^ ])+/echo "line \1 here"\n/ge
```

- it fetches one token (i.e. whatever is separated by the spaces)
- replaces it with `echo "line \1 here"\n` command, with `\1` replaced by the token
- then executes echo
- puts the output of the echo command back into pattern space
- that means it outputs the result of the three echos

---

But an even better way to get the desired output is to skip the execution and do the transformation directly in sed, like this:

```
echo {1..3} | sed -r 's/([^ ])+ ?/line \1 here\n/g'
```